# Add custom block in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

In Magento 1.9 I want to add a custom block to the homepage, but nothing happens. I have these files:

app/design/frontend/[mytheme]/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" as="customblock" translate="label">
                <label>Custom Block</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="customblockreference">
            <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

In homepage.phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customblock') ?>
```

in
app/design/frontend/[mytheme]/default/template/customblock.phtml

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is  reference block  name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you added reference with name "customblock", but then you try to append your custom block to "customblockreference" reference,

try to edit your reference code onto:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="customblockreference" translate="label">
    <label>Custom Block</label>
</block>
```

it should work :)

BR,

Dmitry

Comment: Good answer.. but i  am suggesting to you.If you will change handler from default to cms_index_index for only run at home page

Answer (score 0):

You need to work at layout xml file:

As per as magento `home  page` layout handler is  `cms_index_index`

and you have called the custom block  under `default` handler that means this `block is called at all pages.`

Also  `customblockreference` should be  `homepage.phtml` reference name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="homepagephtmlRefeenceName">
            <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```